# laravel: How to returning multi column after insert into db?

Tags: postgresql, laravel-5.7

I am newbie of laravel.
I got some problems with insert data and returning many columns.

But the document said,

> Note: When using PostgreSQL the insertGetId method expects the auto-incrementing column to be named "id".

insert into (column1, column2, column3) values ('1', '2', '3') returning column1, column2;